# How does Fitnesse invoke selenium server? Can we Expilicitly specify it or Fitnesse invokes randomly?

Tags: java, fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

*How does Fitnesse invoke selenium server?* **Can we Expilicitly specify it or Fitnesse       invokes   randomly?**

Answer (score 1):

FitNesse itself does not test any specific tool, technology, or product. It requires a fixture to communicate with your software. There is a collected list of known fixtures for testing web, rest, database, and other common kinds of apps on the FitNesse web site on the Plugins page: http://www.fitnesse.org/PlugIns. However, this fixture code will frequently be written by someone in the team to connect FitNesse to the unique components of the system under test.

Specifically, you might look at Xebium or SpiderFixture to start.